# Process for multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have this code which works for one pandas series. How to apply it to all columns of my large dataset? I have tried many solutions, but none works for me.

```
c = data["High_banks"]
c2 = pd.to_numeric(c.str.replace(',',''))
data = data.assign(High_banks = c2)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: you want to replace "," with empty string in all columns of your dataframe?

Comment: yes, exactly, because i have numbers in form 1,500.12 for example, I want to get rid of that commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do it like this

```
df = df.replace(",","",regex=True )
```

after that you can convert datatype

Comment: this works fine, thanks. But what about to_numeric part?

Comment: you can convert all columns to numeric like this                                                    `cols = df.columns`
`df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Comment: or a single column like this                                                                           
`df["coumn_name"] = pd.to_numeric(df["coumn_name"] )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the methods `apply` and `applymap`.

Take this for an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1,', '2,12'], ['3,356', '4,567']], columns = ['a','b'])

new_df = (df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',',''))
          .apply(pd.to_numeric, axis = 1))

new_df.dtypes

>> #successfully converted to numeric types
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
```

The first method, `applymap` runs element wise on the dataframe to remove `,` then `apply` applies the `pd.to_numeric` function across the column axis of the dataframe.

Comment: Unfortunetaly, this doesnt work for me, because I need to change data types before removing comma.